# Change the contrast of a pdf

Tags: pdf, contrast

There are many suggestions but they usually apply to documents. They do not work on scanned papers. Is there a way to decrease the contrast of a pdf image altogether?

Comment: The standard answer is to take the scanned image into an image processing software and change the settings there.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest converting the file to JPG to be able to edit the brightness and contrast.
You can use free online sites such as smallpdf.com to convert the file from PDF to JPG, then adjust the contrast in a picture editing program.
If you don't have one installed already, you can find plenty online.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps taking a photo of the original page with good lighting to ensure adequate contrast, importing the photo into the computer and editing to remove unwanted background and border by cropping the photo, then adjusting the contrast and bright and dark, then printing the jpg to a pdf after enlarging to the desired size might give the desired results.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).